# administrative priviledges?

Tags: user-management

For the purposes of the following questions, please make the assumption that you are a Salesforce user with full system administration privileges.  Describe the steps you would use in Salesforce to convert Jane Smith, an existing Salesforce user, to one with full system administration privileges, reset her password and notify her of the password change by email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to her user from Manage user > user and change her profile to system admin.

Now on the same page you will find button reset password. just click that. She will shortly get an email with password reset instructions.

**Note**: If she is a community user then you can't change her profile. You need to create new user for her.

Answer (score 1):

Steps

- Click on Setup
- Search for Users in Quick search box and click on it
- Click on Jane Smith and change the Profile to System Administrator
  [System administrator can only be assigned to users with user
  License:Salesforce] On the same page Reset Password button,click on
  it, user will get an email for Password Reset instructions